# ESRI Resource-Proxy issue

Tags: php, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am working on a web application using the esri javascript api. To access cross domain resources I have to install the Resource-Proxy (https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy). I tried to install the PHP version like described but the test call http://[yourmachine]/PHP/proxy.php?ping ended up with a blank screen and a 500 HTTP error code.

The proxy-verification.php shows that everything should work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should contact the developers.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to enable logging post the contents of your proxy log file?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `mustMatch="false"` in the `proxy.config` (just for testing)

Comment: still a blank site

Answer (score 0):

try following in proxy.config

```
<ProxyConfig allowedReferers="*"
         mustMatch="false">
<serverUrls>
    <serverUrl url="http://path/"
               matchAll="true"
               username="username"
               password="password"
               />
</serverUrls> </ProxyConfig>
```